# Inserting data from form into table using php

Tags: php, mysqli

I just finished installing Xampp and trying it out.
I wrote a php script to connect to my database like this :

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","triology");
$mysqli->select_db("triology");
$table ="users";
```

Now I want to insert data into my database table from a form I have created using php but I am getting an error message from mysql:

> Table triology.users' doesn't exist.

Even though I have created the table in phpmyadmin.

The code to insert into my table is :

```
$mysql = "INSERT INTO $table VALUES('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]')";
```

and my form code is:

```
<form action="index.php"  method="post"/>
FirstName<input type="text" size="25">
LastName<input type="text" size="25"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Please don't worry about sql injection as I am just trying it out.

Comment: Have you checked if table `trilogy.users` exists?

Comment: Double check that you have a table named 'users' in your database 'triology'

Answer (score 0):

The error message you get is pretty clear about your problem. When you see this message, you either misspelled table name when creating or your table is not there or the table is in a different database.
Also another thing after you initiate the connection with mysqli, you do not need the select database again with `$mysqli->select_db("triology");` because you are already selecting your database when you create the connection with new `mysqli("localhost","root","","triology");`
i am not sure but i might cause duplication in your path and cause the problem.